# Get value based on key

Tags: java, regex

What I have wrong? When I set variable param="MOON" I need get 333#444 but I'm getting: 333#444:JUPITER=555. So I just need one value at a time.

```
final String parameters = "WORLD=111#222:MOON=333#444:JUPITER=555:SATURN=666:";
final String param = "MOON";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(" + param + ")=(.*)(:+)(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(parameters);

if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("3: " + matcher.group(3)); // Value that I needed: 333#444
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Regardless of if you've already accepted or whatever answer is accepted, you should update your question to make it very clear what you're actually asking.  Include what your requirement is, some examples of what should not be matches, and what should be.  Otherwise this question won't help others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but maybe what you want is extract all key=value fields? If that is the case you should split your string at the `:` character and process all parts by themselves. Then match those string parts with the regular expression `([^=]+)=(.*)` or, better, simply split each part at the `=` character. In this case you won't even need regular expressions and possibly save program execution time! It's easy to find the `MOON= ...` expression by search for `MOON`.

**EDIT**: I did the following old Java style test program (most probably can be improved):

```
class Test
{
        public static void main(String argv[])
        {
                String parameter="WORLD=111#222:MOON=333#444:JUPITER=555:SATURN=666";
                String[] elements=parameter.split(":");
                for (int i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                        String[] parts=elements[i].split("=", 2);
                        if ((parts.length == 2) && (parts[0].equals("MOON"))) {
                                System.out.println("MOON is "+parts[1]);
                        }
                }
        }
};
```

Output:

```
MOON is 333#444
```

In many cases using a regular expression is overkill, it can often be avoided and you save execution time. If you have a very long string you might just search for `MOON` and from there for the next `:` or end-of-string and then use split, but I would maybe use a regular expression in this case. It all depends if you need the other fields as well or not.

Comment: I want extract only concrete key=value. So first part of your comment is correct, but then I need two septs: 1. split, 2. reges.

Comment: I'll check my rusty java skills and see if I can whip up an example ... stay tuned.

Comment: I would use `split("=", 2);` in case the value contains an `=`

Comment: @hochl Totally agree a regex can be overkill... but in this case, it's not.  The problem domain is very regex compatible, and (IMHO) an algorithmic approach is much messier (in this case).

Comment: Yes, anyway the idea behind my post is that, often, regular expressions are the wrong tool and many problems can be solved without (so a downvote is not warrented -- your choice). As it seems, following the Java documentation, the split function *possibly* uses regular expressions internally (the signature is `split(String regex, int limit)`). Would have to check on the implementation if a one character pattern is really compiled into a regular expression object or simply searched for -- in *other programming languages* (f.e. Python) no regular expression is used for split and thus is faster.

Comment: @hochl You're right, it is a useful answer in this regard... I downvoted on the basis that I think in this case this is not the "right" way to approach the problem (but it's certainly not "wrong", just different) so downvote removed :-)

Answer (score 1):

`.*` is greedy so it gets as much, not a little as it can.

Try `.*?` or `[^:]*`

Comment: +1 - Another term for this is "Greedy", in case you're looking it up anywhere.

Comment: Correct. `eager` is a term I was just playing with in my code. ;)

Comment: yes, thank you, I will use "(.*MOON=)(.*?)(:+.*)", where MOON will be parameter not hardcoded string.

Comment: @Ziletka But that won't work... your first group `(.*MOON=)` will just capture everything leading up to your first instance of MOON (or whatever run-time parameter you put in there).

Comment: I can't see any problem. I've tested it and it works. Do you have some example where it dos not work?

Comment: Perhaps he means it may not be useful to put brackets around everything. Just put brackets around the expression you want to extract.

Comment: @Ziletka `(.*MOON=)(.*?)(:+.*)` matches `WORLD=111#222:MOON=`, `333#444` and `:JUPITER=555:SATURN=666`.  But if you just need the value for 1 key at a time, this'll work.  But a single regex can be used to get all values for each key.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only after the `333#444`, then this works:

`MOON=([0-9]+#[0-9]+)`

This will get you `MOON=333#444` :

`(MOON=[0-9]+#[0-9]+)`

But without knowing what you're explicitly after, and what possible values/formats might be the value for MOON, the list could go on ;-)

This: `([A-Z]+?=[0-9]+(#[0-9]+)?)`

Will get you:

`WORLD=111#222` `WORLD=111` `#222`

`MOON=333#444` `MOON=333` `#444`

`JUPITER=555`

and

`SATURN=666`

And this This: `([A-Z]+?)=([0-9]+(#[0-9]+)?)`

Will get you:

`WORLD` `111#222` `#222`

`MOON` `333#444` `#444`

`JUPITER` `555`

and

`SATURN` `666`

Mix, match, rinse, repeat ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about performance, but it is easy to read, and it look that it works:
update 2012-09-27: added "or end of text" ... |$

```
final String parameter5 = "WORLD=111#222:MOON=333#444:JUPITER=555:SATURN=666:";           
final String P = "MOON";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*" + P + "=)(.*?)(:+.*|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(parameter5);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // 333#444
}
```

Comment: Since you're answering your own question, you really should update your question to clarify what we've been trying to answer for you ;-)